# 2 SQL queries into 1 using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have a table called "Comments" that has usernames, comments and the group that comment was made i.e.

```
Thomas    "Hello"              Group1
John      "A Comment"          Group1
Bill      "Another Comment"    Group2
Thomas    "etc"                Group3
```

And a table called "Groups" that has the group name and who is a part of that group. i.e.

```
Group1    Thomas
Group2    Bill
Group3    Thomas
Group3    John
```

So Thomas all together is a part of Groups 1 and 3 which I would get by:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE username = $username");
```

So that ($sql) holds [group1] and [group3]. I want to select everything from "Comments" where group = any of the groups found in the above query(1 or 3).

So it would kind of be:

```
SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE group = (SELECT group FROM Groups WHERE username = $username);
```

But I am pretty sure you can't do that :P I have looked into UNION and JOIN but I don't think those are what I am looking for are they?

I hope that made sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can actually do it almolst like that.

Comment: [I think they need to make the red box in the documentation for `mysql_query` bigger and redder, because people seem to miss it quite a bit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: @thomas: I noticed that you did not make use of a nice feature of Stack Overflow: You can mark answers as accepted solution by clicking the checkmark under the answer score. That indicates what answer solved your problem and it makes clear that you don't need any more answers. Maybe you like to get though your past questions and verify some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IN()` instead of `=`

```
SELECT * FROM Comments 
WHERE `group` IN (SELECT `group` FROM Groups WHERE username = '$username')
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can use  join

```
SELECT c.* FROM Comments c 
JOIN  Groups g  ON (c.username = g.username )
WHERE g.username = '$username'
```